# REST API - how to design so that only certain clients can call DELETE method

Tags: rest

I have a REST API that will be consumed by two different types of clients. 
Depending on which type of client it is, I want to allow calls to the DELETE method. For discussion purposes, let's say Client A is allowed to delete but Client B is not.

I was thinking of including a token in the querystring that the API checks ... but not too sure what I should bake into this token / string. I guess a shared password would be fine...

Or maybe there's another way to do this. 
Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually a client authenticates at a server using the `Authorization` header. Here you have a couple of different options available with `Basic` being probably the simples to use. Here the header will contain a base64 encoded string of the user or client ID and the password or API-key assigned to the client separated by a colon: `Basic base64enc("userId:password")`. This however should only be used in combination with HTTPS/SSL. Other forms of authentication are possible too. After the client is authenticated the server can use this information to grant or block access to certain resources.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two clients is presumably that they are different users, or presumably one of the two clients simply has limited access for security reasons.

To differentiate the two, you should use the `Authorization` header. This can be as simply as Basic auth, or as complex as OAuth2.